# Access VBA Report Printing the Form Underneath

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba, report

I have a bit of a strange issue that I can't work out.  I have an Access database split into a front and back end.  One of my forms has a series of radio buttons and a launch button, allowing the user to select which report to open.  I have attached a photo of my form below:

[image: Image1]

When the user loads the selected report, it opens in print preview mode, as it should.

[image: Image2]

However, when the user clicks the Print button in the top left hand corner, 25% of the time it doesn't print the report displayed, it prints the form underneath the print preview.  I can't work this one out.  From what I understand, the print preview has focus because the user is clicking the Access print button from that screen.

As I said, this only happens 25% of the time, the other 75% it prints the report normally.  There is nothing done different when it prints incorrectly, and I am unable to replciate the issue, it happens on its own despite seemingly identical user inputs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**
The following code is what is run when the Display button is clicked:

```
Dim strLibrary As String, strFromDate As String, strToDate As String, strCategory As String
Dim strBookType As String, strBook As String, strBorrower As String
Dim booBookSeperatePages As Boolean, booBorrowerSeperatePages As Boolean, booGrouped As Boolean
Dim dteFromDate As Date, dteToDate As Date
Dim strPassedArgument As String, strWhereStatement As String, strAnd As String

strFromDate = Nz(cboFromDate, "")
strToDate = Nz(cboToDate, "")

If Len(Nz(cboFromDate, "")) = 0 Then
    dteFromDate = #1/1/1980#
Else
    dteFromDate = cboFromDate
End If

If Len(Nz(cboToDate, "")) = 0 Then
    dteToDate = Date
Else
    dteToDate = cboToDate
End If

strCategory = Nz(cboCategory, "")
strBookType = Nz(cboType, "")
strBook = Nz(cboBook, "")
strBorrower = Nz(cboBorrower, "")
strLibrary = Str(fraLibrary)
booBookSeperatePages = chkBookSeperatePages
booBorrowerSeperatePages = chkBorrowerSeperatePages
booGrouped = chkGroup

strWhereStatement = ""
strAnd = ""

strPassedArgument = strLibrary & "|" & strFromDate & "|" & strToDate
If cboFromDate.Visible = True Then
    If fraReports = 20 Or fraReports = 21 Then
        strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BorrowDate] >= #" & dteFromDate & "# And [BorrowDate] <= #" & dteToDate & "#"
    Else
        strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[CatalogueDate] >= #" & dteFromDate & "# And [CatalogueDate] <= #" & dteToDate & "#"
    End If
    strAnd = " And "
End If
If cboCategory.Visible = True Then
    If Len(cboCategory) > 0 Then
        strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[CategoryID] = " & cboCategory
        strAnd = " And "
    End If
End If
If cboType.Visible = True Then
    If Len(Nz(cboType, "")) > 0 Then
        If Nz(cboType, 0) <> 0 Then
            strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookTypeID] = " & cboType
            strAnd = " And "
        End If
    End If
End If
If fraLibrary.Visible = True Then
    Select Case fraLibrary
        Case 1
            strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookTypeHasReader] = -1"
            strAnd = " And "
        Case 2
            strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookTypeHasReader] = 0"
            strAnd = " And "
    End Select
End If
If cboBook.Visible = True Then
    If Len(Nz(cboBook, "")) > 0 Then
        strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookID] = " & cboBook
            strAnd = " And "
    End If
End If
If cboBorrower.Visible = True Then
    If fraReports = 13 Then
        If Len(Nz(cboBorrower, "")) > 0 Then
            Dim strSplitter() As String
            strSplitter = Split(cboBorrower, ", ")
            strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[AuthorSurname] = '" & strSplitter(0) & "' AND [AuthorFirstName] = '" & strSplitter(1) & "'"
            strAnd = " And "
        End If
    Else
        If Len(Nz(cboBorrower, "")) > 0 Then strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BorrowerID] = " & cboBorrower
        strAnd = " And "
    End If
End If

If fraReports = 7 Then
    strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "([Digitised] = 'No' OR [Digitised] = 'N')"
    strAnd = " And "
    strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookTypeDesc] = 'Tape'"
End If

If fraReports = 8 Then
    strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "([ReMastered] = 'No' OR [ReMastered] = 'N')"
    strAnd = " And "
    strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookTypeHasReader] = True"
End If

Select Case fraReports
    Case 0      'Sorted By Title
        If booGrouped = False Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSortedByTitle", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSortByTitleGrouped", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        End If
    Case 1      'Sorted By Author
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSortedByAuthor", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 2      'Grouped By Category
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGroupedByCategory", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 5      'Grouped By Type
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGroupedByType", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 3      'Duplicate Books
        MsgBox "Opening Duplicate Books Form...."
    Case 4
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptRecentAdditions", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 7      'Books Not Yet Digitised
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNotDigitised", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 8      'Books Not Yet Remastered
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNotRemastered", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 10     'Borrower's History
        If chkBorrowerSeperatePages = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBorrowersHistorySeperate", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBorrowersHistory", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        End If
    Case 11     'Book History
        If chkBookSeperatePages = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBookHistorySeperate", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBookHistory", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        End If
    Case 12        'Book Lending Count
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBookLendingCount", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 13        'Book Lending Count by Author
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBookLendingCountAuthor", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 14        'Books Borrowed Count
        If strToDate <> "" And strFromDate <> "" Then
            strPassedArgument = "HistBorrowDate >=#" & strFromDate & "# AND HistBorrowDate <=#" & strToDate & "#|" & strLibrary & "|from " & strFromDate & " to " & strToDate
        ElseIf strToDate <> "" And strFromDate = "" Then
            strPassedArgument = "HistBorrowDate <=#" & strToDate & "#|" & strLibrary & "|before " & strToDate
        ElseIf strToDate = "" And strFromDate <> "" Then
            strPassedArgument = "HistBorrowDate >=#" & strFromDate & "#|" & strLibrary & "|after " & strFromDate
        Else
            strPassedArgument = "|" & strLibrary & "|"
        End If
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmBooksBorrowedCount", acNormal, , , , acDialog, strPassedArgument
    Case 20        'Books on Loan Sorted by Title
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBooksOnLoanTitle", , , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 21        'Books on Loan Sorted by Borrower
        If chkBorrowerSeperatePages = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBooksOnLoanBorrowerSep", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBooksOnLoanBorrower", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
        End If
    Case 22        'Lost/Damaged Books
        strWhereStatement = strWhereStatement & strAnd & "[BookStatusID] = 3 Or [BookStatusID] = 4 Or [BookStatusID] = 7"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptLostDamagedBooks", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 23        'Statistics
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStatistics", acNormal, , , , acDialog
    Case 24        'Books Reserved
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptBooksReserved", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
    Case 25        'List All Borrowers
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptListAllBorrowers", acViewPreview, , strWhereStatement, acWindowNormal, strPassedArgument
End Select
```

Comment: It sounds as if, on some occasions after the report opens, something (probably some code) is giving the focus back to the form. When you click print it prints the active object. We commonly provide a destination option, for reports (screen or printer, and open either in preview or normal accordingly) I don't know whether this approach is any good to you, but it might get around the problem. Aside from this you'd probably need a custom ribbon, which prints a report identified in a tag value on the form - and doing that is a messy task.

Comment: Can you add the code for the "F8" button? Is there a `Form_Timer` event procedure in the form (or in any open object)?

Comment: @Andre Done.  I have checked and there is no code under the `Form_Timer` procedure (procedure window is blank for that).